# Bot Framework's context.Wait() not waiting for user input

Tags: c#, .net, bots, botframework

I am starting to develop a simple Bot, evolving from the Echo bot in the documentation. And I've hit an issue quickly.

I have these three methods on my RootDialog:

```
public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
{
   await context.PostAsync("Olá! Eu sou um bot!");
   await context.PostAsync("Qual é o teu nome?");

   context.Wait(NameReceivedAsync);
}

private async Task NameReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
   var activity = await result as Activity;

   userName = activity.Text;

   await context.PostAsync($"Olá {userName}. Podes dizer alguma coisa e eu vou repetir.");

   context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}

private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
   var activity = await result as Activity;

   // calculate something for us to return
   int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

   // return our reply to the user
   await context.PostAsync($"Tu disseste { activity.Text}, que tem {length} caracteres");

   context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
}
```

And my MessageController Post method is like this:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity activity)
{
   await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootDialog());

   return new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Accepted);
}
```

The idea is for the bot to send two messages right away, wait for input with userName from the user, send another message, and then go to *MessageReceivedAsync* where he'll start his echo loop. The problem is the bot is not waiting for the inputs, only stopping at the end of the *MessageReceivedAsync*, where he'll start the echo.

I can't seem to understand why this happens, since from what I've seen the *context.Wait(...)* should make the Bot wait for input, which is not happening. I'm testing it with the Bot Framework Channel Emulator on Chrome, if that makes any difference.

Comment: Is `context.Wait` awaitable?

Comment: @PaulSuart the method reference is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.bot.builder.dialogs.internals.dialogcontext.microsoft-bot-builder-dialogs-internals-idialogstack-wait?view=botbuilder-3.11.0#Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Internals_DialogContext_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_Internals_IDialogStack_Wait__1_Microsoft_Bot_Builder_Dialogs_ResumeAfter___0__). It's not awaitable, it expects an asynchronous delegate

Comment: But here in the tutorial as far as I can see they do not do anything more than what I do after the context.Wait calls. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs @PaulSuart

Comment: Same thing as when I call the context.Wait at the end of MessageReceivedAsync, because there he then waits for input before sending a message again. @PanagiotisKanavos

Answer (score 1):

context.Wait(method) is a little confusing because it actually sets up a “continuation delegate to specify the method that should be called when a new message is received” from: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-dialogs#implementation-details However, the context.Wait(method) in .StartAsync will execute the "method" immediately, since the dialog is being run for the first time.

If you change your code to something like the following, it should work as you expect:

```
[Serializable]
    public class RootDialogTest : IDialog<object>
    {
        public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
        {
            context.Wait(NameReceivedAsync);
        }

        private async Task NameReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            if (!context.UserData.ContainsKey("askedname"))
            {
                await context.PostAsync("Olá! Eu sou um bot!");
                await context.PostAsync("Qual é o teu nome?");
                context.UserData.SetValue("askedname", true);
                context.Wait(NameReceivedAsync);
            }
            else
            {
                var userName = activity.Text;                
                await context.PostAsync($"Olá {userName}. Podes dizer alguma coisa e eu vou repetir.");
                context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
            }
        }

        private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
        {
            var activity = await result as Activity;

            // calculate something for us to return
            int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

            // return our reply to the user
            await context.PostAsync($"Tu disseste { activity.Text}, que tem {length} caracteres");

            context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
        }
    }
```

Edit: another option, that involves fewer changes to your current dialog:

```
[Serializable]
public class RootDialogTest : IDialog<object>
{
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context)
    {
        await context.PostAsync("Olá! Eu sou um bot!");
        await context.PostAsync("Qual é o teu nome?");

        context.Wait(SetupMethodWait);
    }
    private async Task SetupMethodWait(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        context.Wait(NameReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task NameReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        var userName = activity.Text;

        await context.PostAsync($"Olá {userName}. Podes dizer alguma coisa e eu vou repetir.");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }

    private async Task MessageReceivedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // calculate something for us to return
        int length = (activity.Text ?? string.Empty).Length;

        // return our reply to the user
        await context.PostAsync($"Tu disseste { activity.Text}, que tem {length} caracteres");

        context.Wait(MessageReceivedAsync);
    }
}
```

Comment: Tried your first solution, and still doesn't work, still doesn't stop to wait for input after asking for the name. Only stops at the last PostAsync...

Comment: I think maybe it's because of the controller Post method.

Comment: context.Wait(continuationmethod) does not mean the code execution should freeze and wait at this line.  It is a continuation delegate... letting the bot framework know that the next message processed by the dialog should be processed by the 'continuationmethod'.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell from developing with the Bot Framework, the `Conversation.SendAsync()` works like a `context.Forward()` forwarding the message onto the `RootDialog()`.

I suggest directing the user to a separate dialog using such as `AskNameDialog()` using `context.Call()` and process your code there.

Have a look at the samples the BotBuilder provides
https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples they should help you in understanding.